# set Image Resource events not working in the good way

Tags: android

I have an android application which have viewPager, When it started its load the first and the second images perfectly,

When I move my finger to get the next image its work for second and return to previous activity

The code look like this:

```
    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());
        photoView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aaa);
        photoView.setImageResource(myImages[position]);

        photoView.setOnViewTapListener(new OnViewTapListener() {

            @Override
            public void onViewTap(View view, float x, float y) {
                float x1 = x;
                float y1 = y;
            }
        });
        container.addView(photoView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return photoView;
    }
```

I traced the process and I found different events in method "setImageResource"

In the first time the method go on clearly, 
but when movement event happened its called the "super" and previous activity appears again

```
@Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        if (null != mAttacher) {
            mAttacher.update();
        }
    }
```

Can any one explain whats happened !!!

Thank you.